# Placeholder text doesn't display in textarea

Tags: textarea, placeholder

I'm just working on a form and having some issues with the placeholder not displaying inside the textarea.
If I do backspace twice it appears. Tried lots of different suggestions after trolling this site but haven't been able to resolve the issue yet.  Happens in all browsers.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Description:</label>
  <textarea placeholder= "Describe yourself" style="height:200px; 
  width:300px; font-size:12pt; align-top: "name= "profile_description" 
  class="form-control" required></textarea>                   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above lines work well on their own despite the CSS align-top being incomplete.
The issue is with one of your custom class names. Please remove them one at a time to isolate the problem.

**Update**:
On troubleshooting further with @ljean we found that there were whitespaces in the textarea tag leading to this behaviour.

**Update**:
And so here is the code with the whitespaces which were causing the issue removed.

```
<div>
<b class="text-white" style="float:right">Already a member? <a 
href="../login/index.html" class="text-white" style="text- 
decoration:underline;">Sign in</b></a>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  However, I already tried the process of elimination on the class names which didn't help me isolate the problem.

Comment: I've tested it and it works so the issue is not in the code you pasted above. It is in some other CSS style most probably. See this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lypoamje

Comment: Could you also check if there are any white space characters in the text area tag? 
required>[possible characters here]</textarea>
Maybe just delete & retype this part.
I suspect this because you said hitting backspace causes the placeholder to appear.

Comment: Oh my what I can I say it was the whitespace.  Thank you, much appreciated

Comment: Glad it worked. I've updated the answer so you can mark it as accepted for the benefit of others with the same problem.